# How to properly terminate or throw from index.php

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework

In index.php of a Zend Framework app. I check for the existence of application.ini and local.ini.  If these don't exist then I want to exit and put a message in a place where it can be seen such as syslog.  In the context of PHP and ZF1 what is a good approach?  If I throw then that will cause an exit but I'm not sure that it would be logged anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping your application execution in a `try {} catch {}` block:

```
try {
    $application->bootstrap()->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    throw $e;
}
```

This way you'll catch all exceptions, log them to your PHP error log and still see the exception being thrown.

As you can see it uses PHP's [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function.

If you want to write the message to syslog just replace the `error_log` line with

```
syslog(LOG_ERR, $e->getMessage());
```

You can also call `$e->getTraceAsString()` if you want to log the whole stack trace.

Comment: I don't know where the initial entry point is in the context of a PHP Zend app.  There is a line $application->bootstrap()->run() but this is not the actual entry point, and it is called after the attempt at loading local.ini and application.ini in index.php.

Comment: Wrapping the contents of index.php in a try block up to just below $application->bootstrap()->run() works nicely.  After bootstrap then ZF logging can take over.